# JavaFX Platform seems to be dead (closed/crashed)

Tags: java, swing, javafx

My use case is the following:

- I have a GridBagLayout with 9 rows and 1 column
- First 8 rows contain JPanels
- Last row contains a JFXPanel (used to display html, called htmlPanel in the code below)
- I want to switch the JFXPanel with any of the JPanels

I do something like:

```
if(htmlToFront){
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = i - 1;
}
else{
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 8;
}
jPanel1.add(htmlPanel, gridBagConstraints);
gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
//some other gridbag initializations
if(htmlToFront){
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 8;
}
else{
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = i - 1;
}
jPanel1.add(jPanel, gridBagConstraints);
```

The switch is done properly - the JFXPanel and JPanel are in their proper places. But the scene is not shown anymore after a few switches. I mean, after one or two switches everything is ok, my html code inside the htmlPanel is shown properly. But after another couple of switches (and I wait some seconds before making a switch) the html code is not shown anymore.

I did some testing and it seems that Platform.runLater never calls any Runnable object after this problem occurs. It's like it is stuck on another job and I guess this is related to the fact that the html code is not shown (or maybe the platform is closed, but I don't know how to check this or why it would close).

Why does this happen? Maybe the way I do the switch is not good? Is there a problem with the fact that for some miliseconds during the switch the JFXPanel is not displayable?

A more general question would be why Platform.runLater doesn't do anything?

Comment: Any specific reason you are mixing JavaFX and Swing? It could be simpler to use only one.  

Anyway - posting the parts including any `Platform.runLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` could help pinpoint the problem...

Comment: I need Swing in order to use vlcj to play movies. vlcj only works in a Canvas (i need to play up to 8 movies -> 8 jpanels containing canvases). I need to use FX because i need to display html5 code along with the movies that are being played. I only called Platform.runLater for debug purposes, to see if the platform is still up. I don't call it normally - the html code stops being displayed without me calling Platform.runLater or SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Comment: It's also not a problem of resizing to 0 pixels , the fxPanel and the webView have the proper size...

Comment: Try inserting a call to `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` after creating the `JFXPanel`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks man, you saved my life! That was it. I don't know how I didn't see that method. You should add this reply as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch the panes there is a small space of time when the no FX nodes are part of a displayed scene graph. My guess is that if the FX Application Thread happens to process a scene pulse at this time, it detects there is no active scene graph and exits.

You can prevent this behavior with a call to

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

immediately after creating the `JFXPanel`.